# Replace specials characters in column

Tags: python, pandas

```
name company
Mark AmazonÃ¢Â€Â™s Logistics
```

```py
import pandas as pd
df['company'] = df['company'].str.replace(r"Â|Â|¢|™", "", regex=True)
```

This doesn't replace anything.

I want `Amazon's Logistics`

Comment: That is probably a strange apostrophe character, try using ord() to get its value and replace it by that

Answer (score 1):

You can just encode to ascii, and again decode to ascii which will essentially remove all non-ascii characters

```py
>>> df['company'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')
0    Amazons Logistics
Name: company, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string with the unwanted characters and iterate .replace :

```
string = ['Ã¢Â€Â™']
for c in string : df  = df['company'].replace(c, "", regex=True)
```